# (Windows) Forgetting ANDROID_HOME, JAVA_HOME, ANT_HOME (need it for cordova)

Tags: java, android, cordova, ant

At the beginning all my pathes weren't correct for Cordova, but everything worked out fine now (@people still having problems with the pathes(setting some_home): use the commands down below and put java and ant file not into program files!!!)

**Circumstances:**
everytime  I open the "cmd-Window" i have to enter (I'm just posting this in case I'm making a mistake):

```
set ANT_HOME=E:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin
set JAVA_HOME=E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin
set ANDROID_HOME=E:\Users\myName\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
set PATH=%PATH%;%ANDROID_HOME%\tools;%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools
```

If I want to build an app (before doing this) cordova says it couldn't find ant and typping "ant" or "android" into the console, the console says that these are unkown commands.

After stting the pathes everything works fine!

**THE PROBLEM:** I have to enter the pathes everytime. I wrote a batchfile, which I'm running everytime, but this isn't an amusing workarround.

**MY QUESTION:** What am I doing wrong. My Envriomentvariables seem to be right,too (i would like to post an image, but i dont have enough reputation 8/10)!

my  usevariables have:

```
ANT_HOME: E:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin
ANDROID_HOME:E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
path: %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_40;
E:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
```

and the systemvariables:

```
JAVA_HOME:E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_40
Path:
E:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;
E:\Java\jdk1.8.0_40;
E:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\tools; <--added manually
E:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools;  <--added manually
E:\apache-ant-1.9.4-bin;  <--added manually
C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;
C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;
C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
E:\Program Files (x86)\Git\cmd;
E:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
E:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Windows Performance Toolkit\;
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\1.0\;
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Tools\Binn\
```

Comment: "My Envriomentvariables are right,too " - I'd bet a toe this is incorrect. What have you explicitly done to your environment variables, in particular your PATH.

Comment: open the cmd through `run as administrator` see what happens

Comment: take a look, http://blog.revivalx.com/2014/11/02/common-errors-during-developing-android-app-in-mac-linux-and-windows-platform/

Comment: to Henry S.: Okay wrong words. They seem right. I have every "_home" and I looked at pathes (system and user) and they seemed to be right. I will post them later on if the other solutions doesn't work.
to AtanuCSE and Dato Mohammad Nurdin: thank you!!! I will try this right after work. If its the "run as admin" I will freak out. This so often the answer and too obvious :-)

Comment: @AtanuCSE : run as admin didn't help. Maybe its allready at admin mode (title says: Administrator:Node.js command prompt)

Comment: @ Dato' Mohammad Nurdin: your blog is fine! But my pc again forgot it after restart. I edited the pathes manually now and now android is working fine (type android in console or start the emulator with cordova), but ant alwayse needs 'set PATH=%PATH%;%ANT_HOME%\bin' to work properly.

i added my enviroment variables to the question

Comment: BTW: I'm using NetBeans now. Everytime I start it a message, that Java is not found and it will use the standard directory pops up. But beside that everything works fine and the emulator works fine, too.